# AppScript onOpen not working. Log shows it triggers but no output, etc

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I've been trying this for some time.  What I'd like to do is upon sheet opening, copy a value from one cell to another.  Seems simple enough.  My latest iteration is this.  (apologies in advance if I had made a typo, I'm hand transposing it from a different system).  What I put below applies to either closing and opening the sheet or running the function via Apps Script interface.

```
    function onOpen(e) {
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Settings').getRange(2,6).setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Home').getRange(7,5).getValue())
    }
```

Nothing happens.  If I look in Executions log I can see onOpen triggered, without errors.  If I put a `Logger.log("Hello")` in the function onOpen the execution log will not show the logged 'Hello'.  If I put `Logger.log("Hello")` or `Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Home').getRange(7,5).getValue())` in any other function and run it - I will see 'Hello' or the value in the Home sheet.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I have tested the same script and it works for me. It just takes a couple of seconds for the value to appear in the F2 cell from `Settings` but it works just fine. Google Apps Script sometimes fails temporarily for a couple of minutes, so I would recommend creating a new script file, then paste the same code and try again. Deleting cache and cookies from the browser may also help. Let me know if that works for you!

Comment: Thank you @FernandoLara I created a new script and copied/pasted it in there and it worked without issue.  I don't get why, but it worked.

Comment: I am glad it worked. I think this is a very well known, but still weird behavior from Google Apps Script. I posted it as an answer for future references.  If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Posting my answer from the comments for future references:

Google Apps Script sometimes fails temporarily for a couple of minutes, so I would recommend creating a new script file, then paste the same code, delete the old one and try again.

This is a very common "behavior"/"bug" from Google Apps Script as somehow it gets "stuck" for a short period of time and I have heard from a lot of people that has had the same experience. I would recommend reporting this in [Google's issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) showing your results to see if this can get fixed.

##### References:

- [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/)